# condition in if statements

Tags: java

can if condition contain strings?
for example

```
string s="abs";
if(s) or if(s==null) or if(s.equals(""))
```

which among the above are correct?
Also write for integers..

```
int value=5;
```

say

```
if(value) then condition
```

is it correct?

Comment: if(expr): expr can be every boolean expression you like. So if(5) and if("") are not valid. Everything else is.

Comment: ... Just what do they teach in schools these days?

Comment: "not a real question"? "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here."? Really? It might be a trivial question, but it's **really** not hard to understand.

Answer (score 4):

The condition in an `if` statement must be a `boolean` expression.

That means that it must be **something** that is of type `boolean`.

Both `String` and `int` are not `boolean`, so the following two **do not** work:

```
if (someString) {}
if (someInt) {}
```

Of course, you can have `boolean` expressions that contains `String` values in some way. The following **will** work:

```
if (someString == null) {}
if (someString.equals("")) {}
```

They both compile but act differently. The first one will check if `someString` has been set to `null` (i.e. it references no `String` object at all). The second one wil lcheck if `someString` references an empty `String` (one with a length of 0)).

Comment: @Thomas: Sorry, I don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: I thought that you could find 100 questions like this on SO. I was wrong. In this light the answer may be of some value.

Comment: @Thomas: some duplication is actually useful, especially for basic topics like this, because beginners don't usually know which terms to search for and having the same question phrased differently might actually help them find it.

Comment: Agreed. To have real value you could explain why this is not supported in Java. Which is a underlying motivation to get. (Would then even consider to upvote. :-))

Comment: @Thomas - this is a good answer to an average (to poor) question.  If you have complaints about the quality of questions, don't take it out on the answers. (And a discussion of *why* Java doesn't allow this is unlikely to help @indira.)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest considering another option,

```
if("expected".equals(s))
```

The advantage of this approach is that when `s == null` this expression is false rather than throwing a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you cannot do `if (s)` if s is not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

In java expect boolean, nothing is allowed in if condition check.

And even the assignment is not allowed in java unlike any other languages.
But special case like

```
boolean b =false;
if(b=true)
    System.out.println("true");
```

works fine.

as **b=true** evaluates to the boolean value.